# Simplexml_load_file issue, variable gets NULL Value

Tags: php, xml

i've used the simplexml_load_file function in one of my scripts (shown bellow) :

but when i try to show some data from the xml file, it doesn't work.
here is my code :

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('Ay');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
if (!$fileinfo -> isDot()) {
    $XMLFILE = $fileinfo -> getFilename();
    $pathtofile = "http://Mylink.com/Ay/$XMLFILE";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($pathtofile);
    if ($xml == FALSE) {
        echo "failed to load xml";
    } else {
        echo "$i <br>";
        $A = $xml->Organisme->Nom;
                    echo "$A <br>";
        $i++;
    }
}
}
?>
```

The Value of Nom doesn't show on the page, i tried showing the type of $A, and its NULL

I don't know why the $A variable gets a NULL Value, even if the xml file loads correctly
if you can help that would be wonderful
thank you in advance